# Issues with USB-C (Thunderbolt) -> DP, USB, PD port replicator (docking station) (Dell, Lenovo, HP laptops)

Tags: usb, laptop, display, thunderbolt, docking

I need to dock several different types of laptops at one workplace, so I'm looking at some universal docking solution as I have constant issues with USB-C (TB) docking stations supplied by laptop manufacturers.

**I need to dock these laptops:**

Latitude 7280

ProBook G5

ProBook G8

ThinkPad L14 Gen1

**And I've tried these USB-C docks:**

HP HSA-B005DS

HP 1MK33AA

DELL WD19TB

ThinkPad L14 Gen 1 20U1 ThinkPad USB-C Gen 2 Docking Station

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as mutual compatibility. Basically, only charging works. For some combinations it's only display that is working, for some only USB... The HP 1MK33AA doesn't even work with the ProBook G8.

Anyway, I've bought this "dock" off Aliexpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003740650963.html

This thing has the best overall compatibility, works with all above mentioned laptops, EXCEPT:
For the Latitude 7280 (Win 10), USB does not work, which is kinda annoying, since everything else and every  other laptop just works.

I've tried drivers update via Dell tool, via Windows 10, several restarts, etc., nothing helped...

Anyone has an idea what could be wrong or what else I could try?

Thanks a milion!

Answer (score 1):

Software docks (often marked with DisplayLink) tend to be better at supporting more models of laptop, since they use drivers to emulate port replication. However, it's usually at the cost of performance and reliability in my experience. Dell calls these Universal Docks, like the D3100/D6000.

You might have some better luck with a third-party USB-C dock like Kensington, which isn't directly tied to any one laptop brand. Check with their sales or support team on compatibility directly though - it's usually better than trusting device descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Dell K16A/TB16 docking station and my Probook G8 and HP Omen 15.

With the HP Omen it was quite easy. I downloaded the thunderbolt control center application and approved the docking station. This worked and still does work very well.

The Probook on the other hand is a completely different story as the docking station isn't even detected in device manager when I plug it in, but the charging does initiate.

I used a Targus Displaylink dock and this seemed to do the trick, so perhaps it might be worth going with that.